# Baked LightMap Doesn't Loads after Downloading Asset Bundles on Mobile devices

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Scene which has many models. I Baked that scene and got some lightmaps. I put those lightmaps and those models inside one bundle category and that scene in another as I can't add both models and scene inside one bundle category. I can download those models and scene properly and loads the scene. Everything works perfectly but lightmaps don't get load. It loads in Editor but it doesn't work in mobile devices(IOS/Android). I tried logging `LightmapSettings.lightmaps.Length` also and it gives proper output in mobile. But those maps won't load. Anyone knows whats the problem?

Comment: im just curious do you use unity pro? since asset bundle only work for pro

Comment: asset bundle work differently for different platform, make sure you check this script to build base on your target.
[ExportAssetBundles.cs](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/yaeda/5410868/raw/bc194d8f488b1041711c9b86c300478164091860/ExportAssetBundles.cs)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem but try it.

1. Go to **Files**->**Settings**-> Select Android Switch click **Switch Platform**.
   Rebuild your Asset. Name it **AndroidAsset**.
2. Go to **Files**->**Settings**-> Select iOS Switch click **Switch Platform**.
   Rebuild your Asset. Name it **iOSAsset**.

When building the for each platform,load each Asset with the platform Asset it was built for.

Comment: actually my whole scene works, like loading model, scripts, prefabs etc. It just doesn't load baked lightmaps. When I do LightmapSettings.lightmaps.Length I get proper length but it doesn't show in scene

Comment: Yeah some objects(models,scripts) work and some (lightmaps) don't. Try what is in my answer first.